# Arabic Date is not showing in Laravel using Carbon

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

i want to show date and days in Arabic format using Carbon. but it's showing in English.

```
Carbon::setlocale("ar");
echo Carbon::parse()->format('D d F Y');
```

Result: `Sun 12 May 2019`

> Expected result:
>    it should show day and month in **arabic**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Carbon::setLocale() is only for the diffForHumans method, otherwise it uses the gloabl PHP Datetime locals. So if you want to use Arabic you have to call

```
setLocale(LC_TIME, $locale);
```

then use Carbon method `formatlocalized()`

```
Carbon\Carbon::now()->formatLocalized($format);
```

Note that PHP recognizes more than one Arabic locale so you'll have to choose one from [this list](https://github.com/umpirsky/locale-list/blob/master/data/rw/locales.php)

Just make sure you pick one that's installed on the server you're working on or the setLocale() method will fail and return false.

Comment: replaced: PHP::setlocale("ar");
echo Carbon::parse()-> formatLocalized('D d F Y');
error: class php not found

Comment: it's just setLocale() not PHP::setLocale()

Comment: replaced: setlocale("ar");
echo Carbon::parse()->format('D d F Y');
Error: setlocale() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given

Comment: sorry, it's 3 am here I'm not being very clear, check my answer for code

Comment: how to call: setLocale(LC_TIME, $locale); in laravel

Comment: It's just a PHP function, you don't need to do anything special. In your code replace  Carbon::setlocale("ar"); with setLocale(LC_TIME, 'ar_BH'); and that's it

Answer (score 5):

Change the config/app.php locale to your lang then apply this code:

or you can change app locale dynamically by:

```
app()->setLocale('ar');
```

Then

```
\Carbon\Carbon::now()->translatedFormat('l')
```

Or

```
\Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($now->year, $now->month, $day)->translatedFormat('l')
```

and so on...

Comment: Can you improve your answer by adding some explanation? That will make it more useful for future readers unfamiliar with the syntax.

Comment: this answer was flagged for low quality, please better the answer with more supporting info and an explanation

Comment: Change the config/app.php locale to your lang then apply this code:

or you can change app locale dynamically by:

app()->setLocale('ar');

Answer (score 2):

You can use this package instead [Date](https://github.com/jenssegers/date)

This package contains language files for the following languages:

- Albanian
- Arabic
- Azerbaijani
- Bangla
- Basque
- Belarusian
- Bosnian

And more!

**Insatall**

```
composer require jenssegers/date
```

**Usage**

```
use Jenssegers\Date\Date;
Date::setLocale('nl');
echo Date::now()->format('l j F Y H:i:s'); // zondag 28 april 2013 21:58:16
echo Date::parse('-1 day')->diffForHumans(); // 1 dag geleden
```

Comment: Love the fact that it extends Carbon

Comment: @RJFares Yep it's amazing

Answer (score 1):

1. Import Carbon ( use Carbon\Carbon; ) In The Top Of Your Controller.
2. Use Carbon In Your Function Like This :

   ```
   public function index()
   {
       Carbon::setLocale('ar');

       // Your Code Here...
   }
   ```
3. In Your View Use Date Like This:

   ```
   <p>
     {{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($user->created_at)->translatedFormat('l j F Y H:i:s') }}
   </p>
   ```