# How to show the current month in arabic with Carbon?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have this code `Carbon::now()->locale('ar_SA')->format('F')` it should show the current month in Arabic lang but I got `"February"`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56096913/arabic-date-is-not-showing-in-laravel-using-carbon

Answer (score 2):

On the fly you can use `Carbon\Carbon::now()->locale("ar_SA")->translatedFormat("F")`

Applicationwide update locale inside the file `config/app.php`

Answer (score 0):

use package [Arabic-laravel4](https://github.com/ahmedsaoud31/Arabic-laravel4)

github.com/jenssegers/date